# Return same object type user provided in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So i have this Widget I am writing for flutter, it is a Tinder like swiping cards, I want the consumer to be able to provide a List of any type he wants, and i want to use the same type he provides to return in the builder method he should provide:

```
class Swipeable extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> data;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) builder;

  Swipeable({required this.data, required this.builder});
}
```

Where **T** is the type of data the user provides, and it is controlled by the user with no limitations by me.

The consumer should be able to consume the widget like this:

```
Swipeable(
  data: <User>[
    User(
      name: "Zakaria",
      profession: "Geek",
      images: [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533488069324-f9265c15d37f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=594&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583864697784-a0efc8379f70?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80",
      ],
      age: 18,
    )
  ],
  builder: (context, user) {
    return Text(user.name);
  }
)
```

I hope u understood my Question, I'm not that good in explaining stuff when I'm still a newbie.

Comment: What is the question? If you want `Swipeable` to be generic you need to do: `class Swipeable<T> extends StatelessWidget`.

Comment: I want the second parameter of the builder function to be the same type of the provided list

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic class for this.
For more information, consult the [Generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) section in the language tour.

```dart
// The class  ( ↓ note the type argument here)
class Swipeable<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> data;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, T) builder;

  Swipeable({required this.data, required this.builder});
}
```

Type inference should work in your example (you shouldn't even need to specify the list type), but if it doesn't, you can specify the type with `Swipeable<Type>`.

On another note, you may not even need to pass through your list like this. Consider the `ListView` and `GridView` builder constructors, which provide an index instead of an object. You may want to do the same for consistency.